# Getting error in embedding trading chart library in angular 7 project

Tags: javascript, angular, tradingview-api

```
ERROR in src/assets/datafeeds/udf/src/udf-compatible-datafeed-base.ts(243,74): error TS2339: Property 'errmsg' does not exist on type 'UdfErrorResponse | UdfSearchSymbolsResponse'.
  Property 'errmsg' does not exist on type 'UdfSearchSymbolsResponse'.
src/assets/datafeeds/udf/src/udf-compatible-datafeed-base.ts(248,15): error TS2345: Argument of type 'UdfErrorResponse | UdfSearchSymbolsResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SearchSymbolResultItem[]'.
  Type 'UdfErrorResponse' is not assignable to type 'SearchSymbolResultItem[]'.
    Property 'length' is missing in type 'UdfErrorResponse'.
src/assets/datafeeds/udf/src/udf-compatible-datafeed-base.ts(284,21): error TS2345: Argument of type 'UdfErrorResponse | ResolveSymbolResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LibrarySymbolInfo'.
  Type 'UdfErrorResponse' is not assignable to type 'LibrarySymbolInfo'.
    Property 'name' is missing in type 'UdfErrorResponse'.
```

Comment: Please post some code you are using

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzwb5g

Comment: i have written the code there and i have added the charting library to the assets folders src/asserts/charting_library

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'UDFCompatibleDatafeed' of undefined... after embedding getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `assets/datafeeds/udf/src` to `exlude` in tsconfig.app.json

for example:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "assets/datafeeds/udf/src"
  ]
}
```